# Jersey test gives NullPointerException when using UriInfo

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey, mockito

I am creating a application that should be able to create an account using a REST api. When I wrote the `AccountController.java` class everything worked fine. I used postman to verify that I got the right response.

So my `AccountController.java` works correctly but the unit test I wrote with it don't work. When the unit test is executed it returns a `NullPointerException` which results in a InternalServerError within the REST API. While debugging i found out that if I remove the use of UriInfo in `AccountController.java` and return Response.ok() instead of created the test is successfull.

So my question is. How do i properly test/mock a method that returns and URI?

Bellow are all relevant classes and dependencies. The `Account.java` class is in another package. But both the main application as the project that contains `Account.java` are part of the same parent pom. I am not sure if this is relevant to my question.

### AccountController.java

```
@Stateless
@Path("/accounts")
public class AccountController {

    @Inject
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(Account account) {
        final Account newAccount = accountService.create(account);
        System.out.println("Pre uriinfo message");
        //Removing this line and returning Response.ok() removes the exception
        final URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(newAccount.getId() + "").build();
        System.out.println("Post uriinfo message");
        return Response.created(uri).entity(newAccount).build();
    }
}
```

### AccountControllerTest.java

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AccountControllerTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Mock
    private AccountService service;

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(AccountController.class);
        config.register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(service).to(AccountService.class);
            }
        });
        return config;
    }

    @Test
    public void createUserTest() throws Exception {
        final Account testAccount = new Account("testName", "test@mail.nl");
        when(service.create(testAccount))
                .thenReturn(testAccount);

        System.out.println("Create account test");
        //Create a new Account
        final Response correctResult = target("/accounts")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.json(testAccount));
        Assert.assertEquals(HTTP_CREATED, correctResult.getStatus());
        Assert.assertEquals(testAccount, correctResult.readEntity(Account.class));
    }
}
```

### Account.java

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String fullName;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String mail;
    private boolean active;

    public Account() { }

    public Account(String fullName, String mail) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    //Contains getters&setters
}
```

### Test dependencies

```
<!-- jersey version for "Jersey Media Json Jackson" & "Jersey Test Framework Provider Jetty" -->
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.26-b03</jersey.version>
</properties>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers/jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.
Somewhere on this line in `AccountController.java` a `NullPointerException` was thrown:

`final URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(newAccount.getId() + "").build();`

This only happened when using my JerseyUnitTest so i guess Jersey must change some behavior of `UriInfo`.

Eventually I solved the problem by overriding `equals` in `Account.java`.